# Canceling an ngFormControl event firing

Tags: angular

I have a ngFormControl for a search field, which I have subscribed to as follows:

```
this.searchTerm.valueChanges
  .debounceTime(400)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .switchMap(searchTerm => this.locationSearchService.search(searchTerm))
  .subscribe(items => { doSomethingPartiallyInteresting() })
```

In certain circumstances I want to cancel the .valueChanges event firing. Does anyone know if this is impossible?

Comment: What do you mean by canceling? What is the criteria to cancel the event?

Comment: By canceling I mean prevent it from firing temporarily. To provide more context this field is a typeahead field for an address. When a user types an address I want the .valueChanges event to fire, however, when a user selects an address from the list of matches I don't want the .valueChanges event to fire because I don't require the selected address to be looked up by the locationSearchService. I have a method in the component called selectAddress - in here I was hoping to say don't fire the .valueChanges event but if the user types more in the search field then resume listening for changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could leverage the `filter` operator for this:

```
this.searchTerm.valueChanges
  .debounceTime(400)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .filter(() => { // <------------
    return !(this.address === 'don't handle this address'); 
  })
  .switchMap(searchTerm =>  this.locationSearchService.search(searchTerm))
  .subscribe(items => { doSomethingPartiallyInteresting() })
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks Thierry, your solution worked. In my selectAddress() function I store the selected address in this.selectedAddress which is then  compared to the actual field value in the filter.